# When creating scaled Bitmap get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Tags: android

I am new in android and I'm writing a simple game - Tic tac toe game. When I tried to create scaled bitmap of the images using the width and height from onSizechanged() and test it on my device, the app stopped working. This is my TitleView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class TitleView extends View {

private Bitmap title;
private Bitmap playButton;
private Bitmap background;
private int screenW;
private int screenH;
private int scale;
private Paint text;

public TitleView(Context context){
    super(context);
    Context mycontext = context;
    title = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mycontext.getResources(), R.drawable.title);
    playButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mycontext.getResources(), R.drawable.button_normal);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mycontext.getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
    scale = (int)mycontext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    title = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(title, screenW, screenW, false);
    playButton = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(playButton, 100, 25, false);
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, 1080, 1920, false );
}

public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(title, screenW/2-title.getWidth()/2, 10, null);
}
}
```

This is the error:

```
05-26 12:33:38.049 17441-17441/com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe, PID: 17441
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe/com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
                                                                               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:967)
                                                                               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:946)
                                                                               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:877)
                                                                               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:753)
                                                                               at com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe.TitleView.<init>(TitleView.java:28)
                                                                               at com.game.neitstudio.tictactoe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

At the line:

```
title = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(title, screenW, screenW, false);
```

I replaced two variables 'screenW' with two integer and it worked. I tried to print two variables above to the screen and they are: '1080' and '1920'. How can it be zero? I have read some questions about this but nothing says about onSizechanged(). Please explain it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **View.onSizeChanged()** is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old values of 0.

You should not initialize the size in there. As you create the View, **screenW** and **screenH** are both initialized with value of 0. Try this first to see if it works.

Change:

```
private int screenW;
private int screenH;


public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
}
```

To:

```
private int screenW = 100;
private int screenH = 100;


public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

Or you can just entirely remove the method **onSizeChanged()**